# What is the Data Type of an image?

Tags: data-structures

While I recently have started to learn Data Structure, I've noticed that there are some primitive data type, some non-primitive data type, & some abstract data type. But I didn't find anything which is giving answer of my question: If an image is at least something, then what is the data type of this something? Or, if an image or a video or an audio is information, then on which type of data is this information built on?

I have also noticed that opening an image file in a text editor, it gives some garbage type string where some fonts are always unsupported, and mostly all of them are beyond understandable least for me.

Comment: An image is a [composite data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_data_type). An image file is typically a binary format file. Trying to display a binary file as text won't often give you anything of value.

Answer (score 1):

Images are generally stored as a [sequence of binary values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_file). This is what you see when you open them in a text editor.

[This article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_image) gives you an idea about approaches to represent image data in a digital device. During that last decades, many different [data formats for storing digital images](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_file_formats) have been developed for different purposes.

The same is true for video data. You can think of a video stream as a sequence of single images. Correspondingly to the image data formats, there are also many different [data formats for storing digital videos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_coding_format).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are various data types in image processing, e.g., uint8, uint16, single precision, double precision, logical, and char.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

First of all it is a good question. The answer is:
images, audio & video are all stored in binary form and therefore the data type to be used to define them is either "int" or "long" ...preferably "long"
Hope this helped.

Comment: Why preferably long? An 8 bit grey scale image don't need more than a char, as base type for the array...

Comment: the fact that a file is stored in binary form does not at all imply that it should be defined using `int` or `long` as a datatype. Besides, a `long` is 64 bits and the vast majority of binary files are longer than that (if you meant an array of `long`s then you didn't mention that in your answer).